# Call an async (Promise) function from sync function with Express and Node

Tags: javascript, express, asynchronous, promise, async-await

From a basic express index.js file, is there a way to call an async function from a sync function call (**getData** here)?

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// function which calls a Promise
const getData = require('./getAsyncData.js');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/authors/:lang', (req, res) => { 

  const lang = req.params.lang; 
  const getResults = getData( lang );
  res.json(getResults);

});
```

This is how the getAsyncData module looks like:

```
// getAsyncData.js

const getAsyncData = async function () {

  try {

    // Questionable method of recovering the lang parameter here.
    const lang = (arguments.length) ? arguments[0].toUpperCase() : null;

    // Connect to the database
    const connection = await db.connect(true);

    // Get the data
    const {authors, books} = await connection.load();

    // Join results and filter it
    const filtered_results = GetAuhtorsBooks(authors, books, lang);

    // Send it back 
    return filtered_results;

  } catch(e) {

    return null;

  }

};

module.exports = getAsyncData;
```

But in `index.js` the call to `getData` unavoidably occurs before the calls inside the `getAsyncData` module. `getData` gives `undefined`. It seems the only way to get the result is doing something like this in `index.js`:

```
app.get('/authors/:lang', async (req, res, next) => {

  try {
    const lang = req.params.lang;
    const testResult = await runTests(lang);
    res.json(testResult);

  } catch (e) {

    //this will eventually be handled by the error handling middleware
    next(e) 

  }

});
```

Is there any way to get the same result **without implementing an async/await**  functionality in app.get(…) ?

Thank you very much for any advice.

Comment: No, this is not possible. (Of course you can use `.then()` calls with promise callbacks instead of `async`/`await` syntax). But why do you want that, you got a working solution?

Comment: Hi Bergi, thanks for you comment. I failed a test, I would like to know why. It was not possile to modify the index.js above. But the getAsyncData module had to call a Promise. I tried anything I could.

Comment: What do you mean by "*you failed a test*"? What was the error message?

Comment: I applied for a job, they asked me to do a test, and part of the answer has been: "Put the code only in the test file. This is meant to run the tests and call other modules with the actual code which is standard test practise in most languages." The actual non modificable code was the one in call app.get(...) without async functionality. In the test one - the getAsyncData module - I had to call an Promise to connect and load data. I'm just trying to know where I was wrong.

Comment: The only way to know what *they* wanted to see is is to ask them, not us. There is nothing in your solution that is a bad practise, you just didn't met their requirements not to change the code.

Comment: It makes me happy to know that my solution was not wrong. They do not care about my requests for clarification. And there is no direct contact. But that's another story, it's irrelevant here.

Comment: Nothing is wrong. You just did something that they told you not to do.

Comment: Discipline before efficacy, ok, I'll remember.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the lower-level API of `.then()`

```
app.get('/authors/:lang', (req, res, next) => { 

  const lang = req.params.lang; 
  getData( lang )
    .then(getResults => res.json(getResults));
    .catch(next);

});
```

But at that point, you're better off with `async`, especially when your code would get to a point where just getting one data point and returning it isn't enough, and you need to do more things.

You would still need to manually call `next()` or `res.error(...)` regardless, your function will no longer throw or error synchronously once Promises are involved.

Answer (score -1):

Any `async` function will always returns a Promise. express supports route handlers returning promises. You can use this code:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// function which calls a Promise
const getData = require('./getAsyncData.js');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/authors/:lang', async (req, res) => { 

  const lang = req.params.lang; 
  const results = await getData( lang );
  res.json(results);

});
```